# Where can I find the bcompiler dll for xampp 1.8.2(PHP 5.4.X)

Tags: xampp, php-5.4, bcompiler

I am using xampp 1.8.2 on windows xp and bcompiler dll is not present in the ext directory. I installed older xampp(1.7.1) on windows XP and bcompiler dll was included in the ext directory. where can I find the bcompiler dll for xampp 1.8.2(PHP 5.4.X).

The latest dll I could found on internet was for PHP 5.3.X. I saw some posts talking about compiling it using Microsoft SDK incuding Microsoft compilers, but I have no idea about it.

Can somebody compile it and make it available for download and point me to url where I can find it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying to use bcompiler to convert the php code to binary before deploying it at client's place. I have been able to do it with Xampp 1.7.7(PHP 5.3), but it would be nice if I can have it done for Xampp 1.8.2(PHP 5.4) as that is currently the environment set up at the clients place.

Answer (score 7):

No, You can't ....

**BCompiler** is supported upto PHP 5.3 only...

You need to wait for or request bcompiler support team to upgrade it's support...

Moreover You can use Facebook Hiphop's function to compile PHP into C++,  so it might be worth checking out...

[Facebook HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/)

Another one known as **Roadsend PHP Raven** can be used to compile php in c++

[Roadsend PHP Raven](https://github.com/weyrick/roadsend-php-raven)

If you want to encrypt your code then go for  **BLENC Extension**  for PHP. It is supported up to php 5.5

[Blenc Encryption](http://pecl.php.net/package/BLENC)

Compiled DLLs for BLENC can be found [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/blenc/1.1.2b/)