# run php code compiled by bcompiler on php 5.5

Tags: php, bytecode

I would like to run a php script on a IIS 8 server with php 5.5 which is compiled with bcompiler.

Sadly there is no way I can get the original source code and the developer won't recompile it with any other PHP 5.5 compatible solution like Blenc or SourceGuardian
I hate these kind of behaivor specially if you paid for something and it wasn't cheap.

So is there any solution to run the script on php 5.5?

Oh and I don't want to spend more money on decoding because as I said the script wasn't cheap.

Comment: The need for IIS because the company has other server based softwares that can run only on Windows and we didn't wanted to build a new server for our webpages so we went with IIS. I think it would be cheaper to pay for decoding than invest in a new webserver :) but I trying to avoid spending more money into this project. If there is no solution than I will put it on hold and when I have time I will write code my selve.

Comment: ^ You can edit that addendum into your question, rather than adding extra notes in the comments `:)`.

Comment: I wrote that as an answer to a comment which is apparently deleted since than :)

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't ....

**BCompiler** is supported upto PHP 5.3 only...

You need to wait for or request bcompiler support team to upgrade it's support...

Moreover if you need to compile your code with php 5.5 there are other options too see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374347/where-can-i-find-the-bcompiler-dll-for-xampp-1-8-2php-5-4-x/18778541#18778541)

You need original source to run with php 5.5 or shift to php 5.3 you can see php change log for versions details to decide whether php 5.3 satisfies your needs